# Issue with AVPlayerViewController

Tags: ios, swift, avplayerviewcontroller, video-player

I use `AVPlayerViewController` for playing video and it's working fine. But when device map direction is running at that time it doesn't show `AVPlayerViewController` status bar. So I can't close `AVPlayerViewController`.

[image: Map direction is stop.]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code.

```
extension AVPlayerViewController {

    open override var childViewControllerForStatusBarHidden: UIViewController? {
        return nil
    }

    open override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
        return true
    }
}
```